# Has anyone discussed the relationship between Philosophy and Poetry?

Tags: contemporary-philosophy

The fragmentary pre-socratic record abounds in aphorisms, Nietszche wrote poetic & prophetic prose, the continental tradition is highly literary - to the point where it is incomprehensible to the uninitiated (I would even suggest Badious use of Set Theory (a rational mode of thinking par-excellance) is being used in a literary & poetic fashion (despite appearances)).

This shows, I think that poetry & philosophy, far from being mutually exclusive, can illuminate each other. However, it is possible that philosophy phrased in this way can be trasnlated into a normative discursive style; but is this true for all such, or are in some cases something essential is lost?

Has anyone discussed the relationship between Poetry & Philosophy?

**EDIT**:In Shakespeares *Midsummers Night Dream* he has Theseus say:

> The poet's eye, in fine frenzy rolling,
>
> Doth glance from heaven to earth, from earth to heaven;
>
> And as imagination bodies forth
>
> The forms of things unknown, the poet's pen
>
> Turns them to shapes and gives to airy nothing
>
> A local habitation and a name

Comment: That philosophy has been infiltrated by a bunch of wishy-washy poets? Or that philosophers were short on good ideas and started rhyming to fill space? Actually, wouldn't aesthetics include poetry and be a branch of philosophy?

Comment: A large number of very good physicists and mathematicians prefer the beautiful, so aesthetics isn't just restricted to poetry. I would hesitate to characterise poetry wholly in terms of aesthetic, as they also address questions that are of directly human import. Look at the Duino elegies by Rilke. I can't say I understand them, but I am impressed.

Comment: And I would call them wishy-washy at all. They hang in an area of awe & terror & beauty.

Comment: I was just joking about poetry being wishy-washy. There is good poetry.

Comment: I thought you might be. Its hard to get 'tone' in these comment boxes sometimes...

Comment: Look at Cantor's seminal text, "Über eine Eigenschaft des Inbegriffes aller reellen algebraischen Zahlen".  You'll notice that, despite laying the foundations for "a rational mode of thinking par excellence", it is *completely* "incomprehensible to the uninitiated."  I guess it must be literary?  I think your question is vague and/or too general. The most straightforward answer, posed as it is, is this: "Your examples tell us that poetry and philosophy are related and not mutually exclusive."  Interesting problematics can be found, but we need greater precision to get at them.

Comment: @aBathologist: The same goes for any mathematical textbook. :). I think you're right, however I'm not sure how to make this more precise, yet; in which case I think I'll change the question to ask who has looked at these question. I think that was what hoping for anyway.

Comment: Could you scope this a bit more reasonably? "Has anybody discussed the relationship between philosophy and poetry?" is incredibly broad. Also the question in the headline doesn't really reflect the specific content of the concern

Comment: Maybe Heidegger?

Comment: @weissman: I was looking for suggestions of reading matter. I know for example that Plato wrote a tract on Poetics, I'm assuming that he wrote on the form but not on any connection with philosophy itself. I'll think about it a bit more, and try to break/focus the question further.

Comment: As @Benjamin says, there are very many discussions of poetry in aesthetics. You might want to take a look at [these search results](http://plato.stanford.edu/search/searcher.py?query=%2Baesthetics+%2Bpoetry) and work from there.

Comment: @ManoloMartínez I got the idea that he is asking about the relationship of both... as can poetry be philosophical or philosophy poetical?

Comment: Before the advent of written language, it's likely that philosophical knowledge was passed on entirely through verse. There's nothing very special about it, since you can express just about anything in any combination of symbols. The only special quality being that poetry lends itself better to memory.

Comment: My answer to the very specific question - yes, it's sure that somebody has discussed relationship between philosophy and poetry.

Comment: This is very broad and seems to boil down to asking for reading suggestions on the theme of philosophy and poetry... Surely there must be more specific/constructive concerns we can raise in this area :)

Comment: @Hornickel: There is much more to it than that: The SEP on Platos Poetics has this to say 'And yet Plato clearly thought that something of enormous importance hangs on his assessment of poetry, something that goes significantly beyond getting the details of the subject pinned down in a philosophically respectable fashion. One of the most famous lines in the culminating sections of one of his most famous dialogues announces that “there is an old quarrel between philosophy and poetry”'. I agree with him. But as Weissman suggests it needs more scoping.

Comment: @Hornickel: Memorability is part of it, but prior to that is the ability to command attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Heidegger, in his later texts, turns to poetical writing as the most adequate form of language to "unveil the world", in this way, poetic language would fulfill his work that started in a philosophical ground. I'm not sure whether he considers this as a merging of philosophy and poetry, but I think this is a good reference for the subject.

Here an article about this
http://aporia.byu.edu/pdfs/rogers-poetic_uncovering_in_heidegger.pdf

Comment: thanks for this. I've also found that 'In Language and Death, Agamben raises the question of the relation of philosophy and poetry by asking whether poetry allows a different experience of language than that of the “unspeakable experience of Voice” that grounds philosophy'